# Drawing a diagram in LaTeX

Tags: diagrams

[image]

How can I draw this diagram in LaTeX?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436)! Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

• Note this is a Q&A site, not a please do this for me service. What do you have so far.

Comment: For the future, you should provide a MWE, I answered only because you're a new user and I think JouleV's answer, as is, doesn't work for multiline nodes.

Comment: Joule updated his answer, now it's ok, even if it still requires some manual work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was using `tikz-cd` with `smallmatrix`. Obviously you can change the numbers and set a macro to replace each time the small matrix.

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}

\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzcd}
 & \begin{smallmatrix}     0 & 0 & 0 \\      & 0 &            \end{smallmatrix}  \arrow[rd] &  & \begin{smallmatrix}     1 & 0 & 0 \\      & 0 &            \end{smallmatrix}  \arrow[rd] &  &  \\
 &  & \begin{smallmatrix}     1 & 1 & 0 \\      & 1 &            \end{smallmatrix}  \arrow[rd] \arrow[ru] &  & \begin{smallmatrix}     0 & 0 & 0 \\      & 1 &            \end{smallmatrix}  \arrow[rd] &  \\
 & \begin{smallmatrix}     0 & 0 & 0 \\      & 1 &            \end{smallmatrix}  \arrow[ru] \arrow[rd] &  & \begin{smallmatrix}     0 & 0 & 0 \\      & 1 &            \end{smallmatrix}  \arrow[ru] \arrow[rd] &  & \begin{smallmatrix}     1 & 0 & 0 \\      & 1 &            \end{smallmatrix}  \\
\begin{smallmatrix}     1 & 1 & 1 \\      & 1 &            \end{smallmatrix}  \arrow[ru] &  & \begin{smallmatrix}     0 & 0 & 0 \\      & 1 &            \end{smallmatrix}  \arrow[ru] &  & \begin{smallmatrix}     0 & 0 & 0 \\      & 0 &            \end{smallmatrix}  \arrow[ru] & 
\end{tikzcd}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 11):

Welcome to TeX.SX! This is an attempt using simple Ti*k*Z.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\tikzset{every node/.style={align=center}} 
% To align all nodes as centered (Thank you, CarLaTeX, for showing me this)
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[x=1cm,y=0.8cm]
    \node at (0,0) (a) {1};
    \node at (1,-1) (b) {2};
    \node at (0,-2) (c) {3};
    \node at (-1,-3) (d) {4};
    \node at (1,-3) (e) {5};
    \node at (2,-2) (f) {6};
    \node at (2,0) (g) {7};
    \node at (3,-1) (h) {8};
    \node at (3,-3) (i) {9};
    \node at (4,-2) (j) {10};
    \draw [->] (a)--(b);
    \draw [->] (c)--(b);
    \draw [->] (d)--(c);
    \draw [->] (c)--(e);
    \draw [->] (e)--(f);
    \draw [->] (b)--(f);
    \draw [->] (b)--(g);
    \draw [->] (f)--(h);
    \draw [->] (g)--(h);
    \draw [->] (f)--(i);
    \draw [->] (i)--(j);
    \draw [->] (h)--(j);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

You now only have to substitute the numbers with appropriate content.

Comment: You should add `align=center` as a general node style. Otherwise, your solution won't work with multiline nodes.

Comment: @CarLaTeX Thank you very much! I didn't notice that :)

Answer (score 8):

This is a job for `tikz-cd`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usepackage{array}
\newcommand{\mycell}[1]{\begin{array}{c}
     #1 
\end{array}}
\begin{document}
\[
\begin{tikzcd}
&\mycell{000 \\ 1}\ar[dr] & & \mycell{111 \\ 0}\ar[dr]\\
&&\mycell{111 \\ 1}\ar[dr]\ar[ur] & &  \mycell{110 \\ 0}\ar[dr]\\
&\mycell{011 \\ 0}\ar[dr]\ar[ur] & & \mycell{110 \\ 1}\ar[dr]\ar[ur] & & \mycell{100\\0}\\
\mycell{001 \\ 0}\ar[ur] & &\mycell{101 \\ 1}\ar[ur] & &  \mycell{110 \\ 0}\ar[ur]\\
\end{tikzcd}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Wow, nice answer, quack! Is it possible to pass as parameter the number of columns i.e. something like `\begon{array}{#2}#1...`?

Comment: @manooooh Yes, just modify the definition of `\mycell` :)