# How to compact \ncline command with PSTricks

Tags: pstricks

This question in [Drawing a diagram in LaTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/463961/drawing-a-diagram-in-latex).

```
\documentclass[12pt,border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{newcent,pstricks,amsmath,amssymb,pst-arrow} 
\usepackage{auto-pst-pdf}

\makeatletter
\newcommand\NCline[2]{\ncline{#1}{#2}\@ifnextchar\bgroup\NCline{}} %% :-))))
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}
\begin{psmatrix}[colsep=12mm,rowsep=10mm]
           & [name=A1] $000$ &     &  [name=A2] $111$  &      &   \\
        &     &  [name=A3] $111$ &     &    [name=A4] $110$  &   \\
     & [name=A5] $011$ &   &  [name=A6] $110$  &   & [name=A7] $100$ \\
[name=A8] $001$  &  &  [name=A9] $101$ &  &  [name=A10] $110$    &
\end{psmatrix}
\psset{nodesep=5pt , arrows=->, arrowsize=5pt, arrowlength=1}
\ncline{A1}{A3}{A3}{A2}{A2}{A4}     
\ncline{A5}{A3}{A3}{A6}{A6}{A4}{A4}{A7}     
\ncline{A8}{A5}{A5}{A9}{A9}{A6}{A6}{A10}{A10}{A7}
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

The result of compiling:

[image]

Question:

I got an error. How to fix it? 
You can improve it if you have a shorter way.

Comment: please run first your examples by yourself! There is no package `pstrick`!

Comment: @Herbert :((, I have just known I did not load \NCline. :((( If it is loaded, I would not have to ask one question ...

Comment: @chishimotoji: running your examples gives _first_ an error that package `pstrick` doesn't exists!

Comment: @Herbert That is a typo ... :-))

Comment: It is _no_  fun for the ones who want to help that they have first to fix your typos! Because you can see it by yourself if you run your example by yourself!

Comment: @Herbert I will be careful next time ... :((

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`\foreach \i/\j  in {1/3,3/2,2/4,5/3,3/6,6/4,4/7,8/5,5/9,9/6,6/10,10/7}{\ncline{A\i}{A\j}}` is more elegant, isn't ?

```
\documentclass[preview,12pt,border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-node}
\begin{document}
\begin{psmatrix}[colsep=12mm,rowsep=10mm]
    & [name=A1] $000$ &                             & [name=A2] $111$       &                               &   \\
  &                             & [name=A3] $111$ &                                     & [name=A4] $110$   &   \\
  & [name=A5] $011$ &                               & [name=A6] $110$       &                                   & [name=A7] $100$ \\
[name=A8] $001$         &                               & [name=A9] $101$       &                                   & [name=A10] $110$   
\end{psmatrix}
\psset{nodesep=5pt,arrows=->,arrowsize=5pt,arrowlength=1}
\foreach \i/\j  in {1/3,3/2,2/4,5/3,3/6,6/4,4/7,8/5,5/9,9/6,6/10,10/7}{\ncline{A\i}{A\j}}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This is a short way.

Comment: `\foreach` can remember values. `\foreach \i [remember \i as \j (initially 1]  in ....`

Comment: Why not? You draw e.g. `1->3->2->4` and so on. You have only 3 chains which you need to run through.

Answer (score 1):

```
\documentclass[12pt,border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-node} 
\usepackage{auto-pst-pdf}

\makeatletter
\let\NCline\ncline
\def\ncline#1#2{\NCline{#1}{#2}\@ifnextchar\bgroup{\ncline}{}}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
    \begin{pspicture}(5,5)
    \begin{psmatrix}[colsep=12mm,rowsep=10mm]
    & [name=A1] $000$ &     &  [name=A2] $111$  &      &   \\
    &     &  [name=A3] $111$ &     &    [name=A4] $110$  &   \\
    & [name=A5] $011$ &   &  [name=A6] $110$  &   & [name=A7] $100$ \\
    [name=A8] $001$  &  &  [name=A9] $101$ &  &  [name=A10] $110$    &
    \end{psmatrix}
    \psset{nodesep=5pt , arrows=->, arrowsize=5pt, arrowlength=1}
    \ncline{A1}{A3}{A3}{A2}{A2}{A4}     
    \ncline{A5}{A3}{A3}{A6}{A6}{A4}{A4}{A7}     
    \ncline{A8}{A5}{A5}{A9}{A9}{A6}{A6}{A10}{A10}{A7}
    \end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```